# Deal Or No Deal Game Java ArrayList issues

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a basic "Deal or No Deal" game in Java. I'm running into issues with adding and removing to my multidimensional arraylist.
The issue occurs in line 7 of shuffleBoxes() and line 9 of playerBox().

```
package Deal;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class sample {
    public static ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>> boxes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(22);

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        playerBox();
        dealerOffer();
    }

    public static void shuffleBoxes() {
        int [] prizes = {1,2,3,4,5,6,10,50,100,250,500,750,1000,3000,10000,15000,20000,35000,50000,75000,100000,250000};
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
            boxes.get(i).add(i+1);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < boxes.size(); j++) {
            boxes.get(j).get(1).add(prizes[j]);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(boxes);
    }

    public static int playerBox () {
        String[] boxChoice = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ,"10", "11", "12", "13",
        "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"};
        String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a box...", "Choose carefully",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, boxChoice, boxChoice[0]);
        int chosenBox = Integer.parseInt(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
            if (chosenBox == boxes.get(i).get(0))
                boxes.get(i).get(0).remove(chosenBox);
        }
        return chosenBox;
    }

    public static void dealerOffer() {
        int average;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + (boxes.get(i).get(1));
        }
        average = sum / boxes.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you want ?

Comment: `I'm running into issues with adding and removing to my multidimensional arraylist.` It would be good if explain what are the issues. What errors? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You create

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>> boxes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(22);
```

but this does not put anything into the `ArrayList`.  I don't see any references to `boxes.add(...)` in your code, so any attempt to use `boxes.get()` will throw an exception.

It is not at all clear why you think you need a `List<List<Integer>>`.  A multidimensional list is generally code smell. In 99% of cases a different data structure using custom objects will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix @Tom